# How to build a SSDT project with different Target Platform in CI or from msbuild

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools

With a SSDT project in VS 2019 there is a Target Platform which specifies the target database version for the bacpac when doing a build:

[image]

For local development this is correct, but in the continuous delivery setup we want to target Azure Database which is a different option.  Attempting to publish a bacpac file built for SQL Server 2017 results in the error 
`A project which specifies SQL Server 2017 as the target platform cannot be published to Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.`

This happens because, I think, in the bacpac `model.xml` file there is the line

```
<DataSchemaModel FileFormatVersion="1.2" SchemaVersion="2.9" DspName="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql140DatabaseSchemaProvider" CollationLcid="1033" CollationCaseSensitive="False" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/Serialization/2012/02">
```

where the `DspName` is refering to SQL Server 2017.

Is there an option to pass to `msbuild` that will cause it to build a bacpac for a different, Azure SQL Database, target?

I've tried to use a publish profile and specify `/p:SqlPublishProfilePath="Ci.publish.xml"` when ci.publish.xml has been created from an Azure database, but that does not affect the creation of the bacpac.  Indeed the `ci.publish.xml` file only contains a db name and connection string, nothing about the version anyway.

Comment: There is also "Allow incompatible platform" option in the publish profile. That might solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often happens, typing the question makes you think, and in the `sqlproj` file you will see for SQL Server 2017:

```
   <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql140DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
```

and for Azure SQL Database:

```
   <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
```

so passing the option to `msbuild`

```
msbuild /t:Build Db.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any cpu" /p:DSP="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider"
```

Does the trick.